# Why should I use "--wait" when selecting my default editor in git?

Tags: git, shell, terminal, editor, wait

I know the wait flag will leave open the editor until we close the application.

Why is this useful or important? What happens if I do not apply the flag? Are there other circumstances where the wait flag is useful in git?

An example of the wait flag: `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

Comment: You seem to be confused about what it does after all. Git can't proceed until you have finished editing; `code --wait` enables this, so that the command only finishes when you are done with the editing task, and then Git can proceed to, for example, commit a file with the commit message you composed in your editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't.  Or, you should.  It's not really a *Git* issue.

If your editor *has* a `--wait` flag, the meaning of the `--wait` flag is up to *your editor*.

In this case, your particular editor has a "feature" of sorts:

- Run as `code`, it spawns a new editor window and immediately returns to the calling program.  The calling program regains control of the existing window.  The editor may not even have *finished opening* the new window yet.
- Run as `code --wait`, however, it spawns a new editor window and then *waits*.  It waits for that new editor window to signal that the user, who is using that editor window to edit some file, has *finished editing the file*.  *Then*, and only then, does it return control to the calling program.

When the calling program is your own shell, into which you are typing commands, the default ("don't wait") lets you type in more commands, which is nice.  But when the calling program is `git commit` for instance, the calling program *assumes that the commit message is now what you want it to be*, because Git believes that the editor *doesn't* return until the file has been written out.

The editors that Git was designed around, such as `vim` and (older versions of) `emacs`, don't return until you're done editing the file.  So Git assumes that all editors behave this way.  If your editor behaves this way, great!  Git's assumption holds, and we're done.

If your preferred editor *doesn't* behave this way, we have a problem.  We need something that:

- invokes your preferred editor, then
- waits until the editor signals that you've finished editing, then
- returns control to `git commit` or `git rebase --interactive`.

If that program is `code --wait`, great!  We're done.  If not, find whatever program it *is*.  Set that up as your `core.editor` setting.

Answer (score 0):

### Example:

#### If:  `code <your-file.extension>`

When you use `code <your-file.extension>` command without wait flag, this command will open <your-file.extension> but look at the terminal it returns a new line.
[Explanatory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhf7V.png)

#### Else: `code --wait <your-file.extension>`

When you use `code --wait <your-file.extension>`command, it will open <your-file.extension> but look at the terminal it doesn't returns a new line ([Explanatory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3qnt.png)), it waits you until you close the file from your editor, then it returns a new line.[Explanatory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px5Ft.png)